# change border color of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, colors

Using Gridview to display a table stored in the DB, I want to change the border color to #dbddff. It wont accept this or dbddff, what can I do?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" BorderColor="dbddff" AllowSoerting="true" Width="100px"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="GridDataSource">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the BorderWidth property to 1px.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="dbddff"  AllowSoerting="true" Width="100px"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="GridDataSource">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code

The issue is the missing # in the border color. This should work

Answer (score 1):

Could you apply the color via style or stylesheet?

```
#GridView1 {
    border: solid 1px #dbddff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify the color or use the hex code, which in this case you need the # before the hex code. The border has to be at least 1 px in size in order for the color to show up.